# how to make java App the default mail client on windows?

Tags: java, email

I implemented a small mail app in java . I want it to be the default mail client in windows so I can launch it directly from Microsoft Word when i need to send a document as an email.

Comment: [How to change default email client in Windows][1].


  [1]: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555566